# In JUnit 3, Do Tests Share a Spring Container?

Tags: java, spring, session, junit, spring-3

In JUnit 3, are tests run within the same spring container? or does each test get its own container?

What can be done to prevent tests form 'bleeding' session data to other tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the details of JUnit 3, but I recommend that you upgrade to JUnit 4.

Now, if `@ContextConfiguration` (or `@WebAppConfiguration`) is used to specify which application context is used and the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is used to execute the tests, then it is cached between tests. From the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching):

> Once the TestContext framework loads an ApplicationContext (or WebApplicationContext) for a test, that context will be cached and reused for **all** subsequent tests that declare the same unique context configuration within the same test suite. To understand how caching works, it is important to understand what is meant by *unique* and *test suite*.
>
> An ApplicationContext can be *uniquely* identified by the combination of configuration parameters that are used to load it. Consequently, the unique combination of configuration parameters are used to generate a *key* under which the context is cached.

The reference docs continues to list the configuration parameters that are used to create the context cache key.

What kind of session data is "bleeding"? Use the `@Transactional` annotation to rollback any database changes for test that write to the database. The `@DirtiesContext` annotation can be used to re-create the current application context if it gets polluted, but typically that can be avoided by specifying different `@ActiveProfiles`. Read more about Spring's [integration test annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) in the reference docs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to the first question depends on the system running the tests. Eclipse reuses the context. Maven loads a fresh one per test.

Part 2: use [@DirtiesContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)